# How to subtract each entry in one file from the corresponding entry in another file using shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have two files with equal number of rows and columns. I would like to subtract each entry in one file from the corresponding entry in another file using shell. e.g.

```
ifile1.txt      ifile2.txt    
3  5  2  2      1  2  1  3 
1  4  2  1      1  3  0  2 
4  6  5  2      2  5  5  1 
5  5  7  1      0  0  1  1   

ofile.txt i.e. (ifile1.txt - ifile2.txt)
2  3  1  -1
0  1  2  -1
2  1  0   1
5  5  6   0
```

I was doing like the following which looks very mannual and can't be a good idea for large number of rows and columns.

```
paste ifile1.txt ifile2.txt > ifile3.txt
awk '{printf("%f %f %f %f\n", $1-$5, $2-$6, $3-$7, $4-$8);}' ifile3.txt > ofile.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle an arbitrary number of columns, you need a `for` loop:

```
$ awk '{n=NF/2; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%5.2f ", $i-$(i+n); print ""}' ifile3.txt
 2.00  3.00  1.00 -1.00 
 0.00  1.00  2.00 -1.00 
 2.00  1.00  0.00  1.00 
 5.00  5.00  6.00  0.00
```